# What are the minimum permissions to grant an Exchange 2007 admin to perform specific mailbox management tasks?

Tags: exchange-2007, user-management, security, remote-access

I would like to allow someone else to administer user accounts and mailboxes (add users, reset passwords, disable accounts) on an Exchange 2007 server.

Obviously, they should not be able to disable or alter the administrator accounts or make any other type of changes to the server.

Please advise what is the minimum security permissions I should grant them so they can perform these functions alone.

Answer (score 4):

I'm no exchange pro, but I think you'll find that you'll need to perform most of these functions in Active Directory, not in Exchange. Changing a password is something you do in AD. While you can add mailboxes and suspend mailboxes in Exchange separate from the AD user's windows account, it's really something you should be doing in AD User Management so the settings apply to all MS services.

Have a look at the permissions of the Domain Admins or similar groups, and see if you can replicate some of the AD rights that you need in a new group.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to install www.websitepanel.net and use it for administration purposes which provides a Web interface the achieves my objectives of only giving access to the add / edit / remove mailboxes and users options while removing all root access to the server directly.